# Nutch 2 hsql configuration

Tags: hsqldb, nutch

How can i configure data mapping in this database using nutch. Probably should be some hsql-mapping.xml but the compiled nutch don't have this file. 
I am asking this because sometimes i get a sql error due to data truncation, so i need to alter the datalength of  the fields.

Thanks

Comment: which version of nutch are u using ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say, its the 2.0.

By the way, i think i found the solution, more exactly a workaround:

I've altered the auto generated class Webpage and redefined is getters and setters.